# Tikz: path generating a large blank space

Tags: tikz-pgf

Let's suppose the following situation (wich is the simplest I could think): a circle intersepts two different points of a line and we call these points C and D.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt]{article}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\begin{document}
And here we've got a text about whatever it's talking about and probably is introducing this:
    
    \begin{figure}[h!]
    \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \coordinate (A) at (-2,0);
        \coordinate (B) at (2,0);
        \coordinate (P) at (0,1);
        \draw [name path=line] (A)--(B);
        \draw [name path=circle] (P) circle (1.5cm);
        \path [name intersections ={of=line and circle,name=N,total=\t}];
        \node at (N-1)[below left]{C};
        \node at (N-2)[below right]{D};
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}

Which lead us to the meaning of the figure.
\end{document}
```

[image]

My situation actually uses the through library, would be, in the example, something like giving a point (C or D) of the line and drawing a circle from P passing through this point. I don't really know if it does change the problem. The thing is: what if I just wanted the coordinates? Instead of using \draw, I'd use \path (or \node at (?) [circle through (...)];) and whatever commands to simply get the coordinates. In the example, I just switched `\draw [name path=circle] (P) circle (1.5cm);` to `\path [name path=circle] (P) circle (1.5cm);`

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt]{article}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\begin{document}
And here we've got a text about whatever it's talking about and probably is introducing this:
    
    \begin{figure}[h!]
    \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \coordinate (A) at (-2,0);
        \coordinate (B) at (2,0);
        \coordinate (P) at (0,1);
        \draw [name path=line] (A)--(B);
        \path [name path=circle] (P) circle (1.5cm);
        \path [name intersections ={of=line and circle,name=N,total=\t}];
        \node at (N-1)[below left]{C};
        \node at (N-2)[below right]{D};
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}

Which lead us to the meaning of the figure.
\end{document}
```

[image]

This huge blank space. How to get rid of it in order to get something like this:

[image]

By the way, for the last image I just typed C and D coordinates as approximations of the actual X coordinate for both of them.

Comment: Even if paths are not drawn, they still contribute to the bounding box. So you may want to use `\path [name path=circle,overlay] (P) circle (1.5cm);` in the second example, as well as `\path[overlay] (0,1) coordinate (P);`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if paths are not drawn, they still contribute to the bounding box. So you may want to use the `overlay` key on auxiliary paths and coordinates. `overlay` makes sure that they do not contribute to the bounding box.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\begin{document}
And here we've got a text about whatever it's talking about and probably is introducing this:
    
    \begin{figure}[h!]
    \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \path (-2,0) coordinate (A) (2,0) coordinate (B);
        \path[overlay] (0,1) coordinate (P);
        \draw [name path=line] (A)--(B);
        \path[overlay,name path=circle] (P) circle[radius=1.5cm];
        \path [name intersections ={of=line and circle,name=N}];
        \node at (N-1)[below left]{C};
        \node at (N-2)[below right]{D};
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}

Which lead us to the meaning of the figure.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to reset the bounding box and recreate it to include only specific nodes and scopes (using local bounding boxes).

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt]{article}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{intersections,fit}
\begin{document}
And here we've got a text about whatever it's talking about and probably is introducing this:
    
    \begin{figure}[h!]
    \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \coordinate (A) at (-2,0);
        \coordinate (B) at (2,0);
        \coordinate (P) at (0,1);
        \draw [name path=line] (A)--(B);
        \path [name path=circle] (P) circle (1.5cm);
        \path [name intersections ={of=line and circle,name=N,total=\t}];
        \node (C) at (N-1)[below left]{C};
        \node (D) at (N-2)[below right]{D};
        \pgfresetboundingbox
        \node[fit=(A) (B) (C) (D)] {};
        \draw[red] (current bounding box.south west) rectangle (current bounding box.north east);
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}

Which lead us to the meaning of the figure.
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]